# In blockchain, if no new members join the network can we prove that there will not be anymore forks before a certain point in history?

Tags: consensus

I would like to know if we can allow new members to join with the promise that they will not attempt to create a new fork however hard it may prove to be, before a certain point in history. To this effect; if no new members join the network for let's say a month, can we prove that there will not be anymore forks before a certain point in history?

I frankly feel the two statements are paradoxical. Actually I want to know if we can add a rule to the blockchain to say if it ran for a month with at most N number of nodes and all did not fork, then the network won't allow forks before that point in time, starting from let's say 2 months later.

Comment: Are you asking about a rolling checkpoint?

Comment: What happens if two people disagree on whether or not N nodes did not fork? Then won't they disagree on whether or not to invoke fork protection? You need some kind of consensus algorithm for how to agree on whether or not N nodes did not fork and then you see you have a huge chicken and egg problem.